# attach a child sprite to animated sprite andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to learn game programming using AndEngine.  I have created animated sprites that are spawned on different intervals. I would like them to shoot objects at my player.  I have searched trying to learn how others have done this, and tried the code that i thought would get me started, but have been unsucessful.  Can someone pleae point me in the right direction to accomplish attaching a child sprite and having it shoot at different intervals in AndEngine.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Your 'bullets' will not be attached to your 'shooter'!

Comment: Hi Nicolas, Thank you for your reply and AndEngine!  In that case will i create a TimerHandler, iterate through my tartgets pools, and attach the objects using a MoveModifier?  I'm just really not sure how to implement this.

Comment: What I meant is that the bullets won't be children of your player, but siblings. Because if they are children and you move/rotate the player, the bullets would move/rotate along, which would look very awkward.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to attach bullets as child, [here](http://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/jimvaders-my-own-invaders-clone-thingie-tutorial/) is the very good tutorial and it's shooting bullets :), You're in luck!